# analytic solution of system of non-linear algebraic equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

Can we solve analytically a system of non-linear algebraic equations? In particular something of this form( $x_k$ are the unknowns):
$$b_1 = a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2+....+ a_{1k}x_k$$ 
$$b_2 = a_{21}x_1^2 + a_{22}x_2^2 + .....+ a_{2k}x_k^2$$
$$b_3 = a_{31}x_1^3 + a_{32}x_2^3 + ......+ a_{3k}x_k^3$$

Please suggest some material which deals with analytic solution of system of non-linear equations.
thanks

Comment: Do you mean $x=x_1$ ? Could we use [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) ?

Comment: I just edited it. I know about Vandermonde matrix. How to use it here? thanks